# Adding Vulkan to 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, vulkan

I have followed the instructions from [this article on LinuxConfig](https://linuxconfig.org/install-and-test-vulkan-on-linux).
This is the readout I get:

```
kim@kim-MS-7917:~$  sudo apt install nvidia-graphics-drivers-396 nvidia-settings vulkan vulkan-utils
[sudo] password for kim: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-graphics-drivers-396
E: Unable to locate package vulkan
```

So, these are the wrong packages then? I searched packages.ubuntu.com for packages in focal with 'vulkan' in the name. There's `libvulkan1` which is a loader library, so that's needed I guess.

My Ubuntu is currently using nvidia-driver-460.

Comment: It's baffling that an article posted in March 2021 mentions an old and deprecated driver version for no reason. Everything else looks fine (at first glance) so just install the recommended driver version instead - open Additional Drivers, select and install the recommended version, no need to add the graphics drivers PPA, if you already added it then remove it before installing the Nvidia driver - then install the other suggested packets.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Alright entering`sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` listed the 470 package as recommended so I switched. When I tried installing `libvulkan1` it was already there. So now I'm thinking, Did I even need to add Vulkan manually? Is it already there?

Comment: If I remember correctly by the time of 20.04 release it only needed something like https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/vulkan-tools .